# Updating Symfony 2.1 (Subversion)

Tags: php, svn, symfony, composer-php

I would like to update my Symfony 2.1.1 (trunk) to 2.1.2, but running `composer update` deletes folders containing .svn files. How do I properly update it?

Comment: you shouldn't add vendors (like symfony) to your app's repository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cyprian is right, the contents of the vendor folder should be excluded from SVN.

You accomplish this by setting the svn:ignore property to value "*" on the vendor folder, or ignoring the vendor folder.

Since you already have the folders in the repository, the way to go is to remove the contents of the vendor folder with svn (svn rm), and committing that change.
After that, add the ingore property and commit.

When you run composer install or update in the future, this will not affect your repository.

Comment: Doesn't this run the risk of an external source of code suddenly disappearing and leaving your app incomplete?

Comment: @Craig My answer should be performed once; it keeps the external vendor libraries out of your version control system.

Obviously, the dependency on the external library still exists; I've heard it stated that Composer - while useful - als poses a risk as the repository (packagist) is a single point of failure.
[source](http://css.dzone.com/articles/including-php-libraries)

Comment: What do you mean it should be performed once? I understand that setting svn:ignore doesn't need to be called multiple times, but that doesn't solve the issue of not having a local backup of all the source your app relies on.

Comment: What I'm saying is, your verion control repository is not the place to "keep a backup" of al source your application relies on.

Comment: What about the bin folder that has links into the vendors folder?